# multiple slides swiper - refresh page changes behavior

Tags: swiper.js

I am having a weird issue, I hope you will be able to help.
I have installed the swiper version : Loop Mode with Multiple Slides Per Group with 3 slides per group.

Works great except when I refresh the page : then I have only 2 slides and I can only display one more slide (it misses one).
If I do a control + F5 then works great again.

I don't have a clue on why I am getting this strange behavior..hope you can help

Comment: In fact after several test, I believe swiper increases the space between slides when refreshing

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution by seeting the width of the swiper-slide element